# How can I get only the first result of ZRANGEBYSCORE?

Tags: redis

Right now I'm trying something like the following command.

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myzset myvalue inf
```

It gets me the all the results greater than `myvalue`. However, I would like to obtain only the first result. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myzset myvalue +inf LIMIT 0 1
```

Note: use `+inf`, not `inf`

Comment: Damn, sorry, I skipped that part. Thanks!